# count frequency random numbers which specific range in c array

Tags: c

I'm trying to count the frequency of numbers in specific area like
0<=number<16 ,87<=number<100 .

I have tried to use if block inside for loop and tried to increment 
main(){int sum=0;}

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
    int a[5]={0};
    int i,n,sum=0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        n=1+rand() % 100;
        a[n/20]++;

    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(0<=a[i]<=16){
            sum++;
        }


    } printf("%d",sum);
}
```

I should have get different numbers on output but output was always same number "5"

Comment: When `n==100`, `a[n/20]++;` is UB as it attempts to access `a[]` outside its range.

Comment: Observe that `1 + rand() % 100` never generates 0.  I'm also unsure what the "like 0<=number<16 ,87<=number<100" part of the question means (beyond apparently meaning that the case where `n == 100` should not be counted).  Is it looking for two specific ranges: 0..15 and 87..100, or is it looking for vaguely similar ranges with 6 sets of values — 0..15, 16..31, 32..49, 50..65, 66..83, 84..100 or something? (The questions requests 87 rather than 84 or thereabouts, and I'm not sure how that should work, especially as the code uses 5 ranges nominally 0..19, 20..39, 40..59, 60..79, 80..99.)

Comment: Yes 100 is not counted in range ,It is between 0-100 and it should be 5 specific range but these range are not increase regular .

Comment: Then you need to expand your question to explain how the 5 irregular ranges are defined.  You should probably drop the `1 +` from the calculation of `n`.  And the `n/20` will not be correct.  It then isn't clear why you only want the count of the ranges where there are 16 or fewer samples — the `a[i] >= 0` condition will be always true since the array is initialized to zeros and the elements are never decremented.  It's generally a good idea to end `printf()` format strings with a newline (`"%d\n"`); it helps ensure the output is produced timely (and without screwing up command line prompts).

Comment: Condition `0<=a[i]<=16` most likely does not work the way you think (a[i] >= 0 && a[i] <= 16`).

Comment: Generally adding some extra prints while debugging is a good idea (like printing the array initialization, printing any `a[i]` that matches the condition).

Answer (score 3):

```
if(0<=a[i]<=16){
```

Is not the correct expression.  It is always true since (0<=a[I]) will always be true (1) or false (0).  Both values are less than 16.  You want something like this:

```
if ((a[i] >= 0) && (a[i] <= 16))
```

By the way, always pay attention to the compiler warnings.  In this case it told me exactly what the problem was.